# how set itext pdf file name from action class

Tags: java, struts2, struts, itext

i am working with struts2 and using itext for generating Pdf file.
But my PDF file name are static. i have set file name in struts.xml(Code given below).

```
 <action name="form12PdfReport" class="plantHR.Form12PdfReport" method="form12PdfReport">
        <interceptor-ref name="myStack" />
         <result name="success" type="stream">
            <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param>
            <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
            <param name="contentDisposition">filename="form12PdfReport.pdf"</param>
            <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
        </result>
     </action>
```

Can i set filename="anyFilename" dynamically from action class??

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

In your class, define a private properties with its getter:

```
private String pdfFileName;

public String getPdfFileName(){
   return pdfFileName;
}
```

then set is in the `execute()` method;

and instead of

```
<param name="contentDisposition">filename="form12PdfReport.pdf"</param>
```

write

```
<param name="contentDisposition">filename="${pdfFileName}.pdf"</param>
```